# Problems setting new SmartGWT Theme 'Tahoe'

Tags: java, html, gwt, smartgwt, isomorphic

Helly everybody,
I'am trying to set in an sample gwt project (greeting service) the new 'Tahoe' Theme which is available in smartgwt version 6.1.
I hope somebody could give me some usefull hints.
My problem is, that i set all to use the new theme but if i open the project inside my browser the new skin is not working.

My code:
test.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
  "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='gwtclientserverexample'>

  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript" />

  <inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.tahoe.Tahoe" />

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.sample.gwt.client.GWTClientServerExample'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

   </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isomorphicDir = "gwtclientserverexample/sc/";
    </script>

    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>

    <!--include SmartClient -->
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/modules/ISC_Drawing.js?isc_version=10.1.js"></script>

    <!--load skin-->
    <script src="gwtclientserverexample/sc/skins/Tahoe/load_skin.js?isc_version=9.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="gwtclientserverexample/gwtclientserverexample.nocache.js"></script>


    <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>

    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter your name:</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
        <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I open my browser the project looks so:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use this tag

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript" />
```

it will stop any script being loaded from your index.html file (including your Tahoe theme load_skin.js )

The correct tag to use for the LGPL version, if you just want to switch the default theme is

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoTheme"/>
```

You can find info related to this in the quickstart guide https://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf on page 81, under 'Switching Theme'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if i include <inherits name="com.smartgwtee.SmartGwtEENoTheme"/> i got the following error:  [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/smartgwtee/SmartGwtEENoTheme.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source? I'am using the LPGL-Version from SmartGWT.

Comment: Ah really? Sorry, I thought it was com.smartgwtee.SmartGwtEENoTheme" for all versions. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the help from @Alan.

I needed to include:

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoTheme" />
```

and not:

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwtee.SmartGwtEENoTheme"/>
```

After that i could include the new Tahoe-Skin:

```
<inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.tahoe.Tahoe" />
```

My *.gwt.xml looks now so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
  "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='gwtclientserverexample'>

  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoTheme" />
  <inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.tahoe.Tahoe" />

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.sample.gwt.client.GWTClientServerExample'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```